# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard::login()

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error while trying to login API

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard::login() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, instance of App\User given, called in /home/scrixmll/apiadmin.silexsecure.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 307 in file /home/scrixmll/apiadmin.silexsecure.com/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTGuard.php on line 140

Comment: please put your controller code.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject` in your user model

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
....
```

And declare the needed methods

```php
    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
```